# 'Plane crash' web font is not working in website sentence showing as unknown characters

Tags: css, font-family

My client want plane crash webfont for website. I am trying form the link
https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/3453d125efb5686a2f6692e90785608f

sentence showing as set of unknown characters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noyGi.png)

Is there any way to use plane crash font in website?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Plane Crash font only supports lowercase letters (as letters), and renders uppercase as icons (see: http://www.dafont.com/plane-crash.font). Try using a CSS `text-transform: lowercase` on any elements with actual text, and if you need the icons, put them into another element with `text-transform: uppercase`. So, for instance:

HTML:

```
<span class="pc">This is a sentence with mixed upper-lower <span class="pc-icon">M</span></span>
```

(the "M" would show as an icon from the font)

CSS:

```
/* After all your usual @font-face stuff... */
.pc, .pc-icon {
    font-family: "Plane Crash";
}
.pc {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.pc-icon {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: wow:) Thanks SuperELEB. Its working. you really saved my day.. Good job:)